# phpMyAdminでインポート出来ているのに、出来ていない

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

画像の通り、SQLソース、38,767 バイト（ディスク上の41 KB）をインポートし、
画面にインポートは正常に終了しました。44個のクエリを実行しました。(create.sql)と
ありますが、インポートされた形跡がないです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

解決策をネットで調べようとしましたがヒントが見つかりません。
この現象は何が原因だと考えられますか。

＊ファイルの中身は業務で使うものなので公開はできません。

お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: sqlの問題かphpmyadminの問題かまずは切り分けるために、適当なSQLをインポートするとどうなりますか？問題なくインポートできますか？

Comment: すいません。上記インポートしたものが格納されている事が確認できました。せっかくコメントして頂いたのに申し訳ございません。

Comment: 解決したのであればご自身で回答をしてください。

Answer (score -1):

よく見たらインポートされてました。

単なる見落としでございます。

大変お騒がせしました。